# adding an int to int in a list comprehension fails

Tags: python, nonetype, operand

in this statement

```
stop_words_index = [word_index.get(w) + 3 for w in stop_words]
```

word_index.get(w) is an int, but this statement generates

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

How to fix this?

Comment: You should do `get(w, 0)`, in case `get` returns None when `w` is not found in `word_index`

Comment: `word_index.get(w)` is obviously not a int

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you are trying to access a hash that doesn't exist, hence the nonetype

Comment: Have a look at `[w for w in stop_words if w not in word_index]`

Comment: you guys are too quick. I just discovered myself.

Comment: You should always be wary when you use `get` without a second argument, especially embedded in a larger expression. If `w` is always going to exist, you should be doing `[w]` rather than `.get(w)`. If it isn’t always going to exist, you need to think about what value you want when it doesn’t, because often—as here—it’s going to be 0 or 1 or an empty string or something, not `None`.

Answer (score 2):

`word_index.get(w)` is `None` if `w` cannot be found in dictionnary `word_index`.

You should do `word_index.get(w, 0)` if you want this value to be 0 when `w` is not found.

Or `[word_index.get(w) + 3 for w in stop_words if w in word_index]` if you want to skip the not found words.